# Как получить runtime разрешение на чтение памяти устройства android?

Tags: android, файловая-система, android-dialog

У меня есть диалог в котором я пытаюсь отобразить директории устройства. Временами все работает нормально, и даже красиво, то есть отображаются все директории и файлы. Я например на эмуляторе тестирую и все работает нормально, дальше я пробовал несколько дней тому на телефоне, и там тоже все директории и файлы показывает как нужно. Но вот сегодня я попробовал у себя на телефоне опять отобразить в диалоге файловую систему, и у меня ничего не получилось. То есть путь правильный, и все должно было работать но почему-то у меня был только пустой диалог без списка директорий. Вот мой метод, в котором я работаю с выводом директорий:

```
root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
curFolder = root;
```

вот построение диалога:

```
dialog = new Dialog(WriteResponseMess.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

                textFolder = dialog.findViewById(R.id.folder);
                buttonUp = dialog.findViewById(R.id.up);
                buttonUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        ListDir(curFolder.getParentFile());
                    }
                });


                dialog_ListView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglist);

                dialog_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                        File selected = new File(curFolder, fileList.get(position));
                        if (selected.isDirectory()) {
                            ListDir(selected);
                        } else {
                            if (array.size() == 0) {
                                array = new JsonArray();
                                array = uploadFiles(array, selected.getName(), convertFileToString(selected.getPath()));
                            } else {
                                if (array.toString().contains(selected.getName())) {
                                    Log.w("MY_TAG", "CONTAINS");
                                    Toast.makeText(WriteResponseMess.this, R.string.attaching_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    array = uploadFiles(array, selected.getName(), convertFileToString(selected.getPath()));
                                }

                            }
                            //Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(array.getAsJsonArray()));
                            ms.setArray(array);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

вот формирование списка:

```
@Override
    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);

        switch (id) {
            case CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID:
                ListDir(curFolder);
        }
    }

    void ListDir(File f) {
        if (f.equals(root)) {
            buttonUp.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            buttonUp.setEnabled(true);
        }

        curFolder = f;
        textFolder.setText(f.getPath());
        String[] files = f.list();
        fileList.clear();
        if (files != null) {
            fileList.addAll(Arrays.asList(files));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
        dialog_ListView.setAdapter(directoryList);
    }
```

я не могу понять как и почему у меня не всегда отображается моя файловая система. Ведь иногда она выводится в список и все нормально.

### update

я нашел причину странного поведения моего диалога - у меня не было разрешения для чтения памяти устройства, и теперь собственно вопрос, как мне его получить в процессе работы приложения. Потому что по-моему глупо просить у пользователя идти в настройки и поставить разрешение мануально. Может есть готовое решение с учетом моей задачи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После поисков на просторах интернета я набрел на вполне рабочий способ. У меня этот диалог со списком файлов и папок формируется при нажатии на кнопку, поэтому я добавил такой метод:

```
 public boolean isReadStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v("MY_TAG", "Permission is granted1");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.v("MY_TAG", "Permission is revoked1");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 3);
                return false;
            }
        } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v("MY_TAG", "Permission is granted1");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

и дальше при при нажатии на кнопку я проверяю:

```
if(isReadStoragePermissionGranted())
{
//показываю список файлов
}
```

на данный момент вроде все работает так как нужно. Вот ссылка на [первоисточник](https://mobikul.com/getting-read-write-permission-external-storage-android/). Надеюсь кому-то поможет.